# flask - unable to run a variable to a list in for loop to store the sql database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm unable to loop through the "query" variable with the items list and push the code to database. but it is throughing an error ""ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"", can someone check the code please?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            query = request.form['url']
            r = requests.get(query)
            output = r.json()
            items = output['result']

            # # items = ['abc','bcd','cde','def'] # here items will be in list

            for i in items:
                user = User(listOfItems=items[i], query=query)
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()

            responseBody = {'message': items}
            return make_response(jsonify(responseBody))
        except Exception, e:
            return ('Oops!', e.__class__, 'occurred.')
    else:
        responseBody = {'message': 'failed'}
        return make_response(jsonify(responseBody))
```

**desired output in database:**

```
listOfItems     query           time_stamp
abc            example.com      -date-
bcd            example.com      -date-
cde            example.com      -date-
def            example.com      -date-
xyz            example1.com      -datetime.now-
yza            example1.com      -datetime.now-
zab            example1.com      -datetime.now-
```

here,
query1: example.com returns ['abc','bcd','cde','def'] list items
query2: example1.com returns ['xyz','yza','zab'] list items

Comment: The line `user = User(listOfItems=items[i], query=query)`, should just be `user = User(listOfItems=i, query=query)` since `i` is the item not the index. And the error most likely from `User` class.

Comment: Thanks for helping out and now error is gone, but in database it is showing only 1 row i.e. ```abc            example.com        -date- ```
it is not iterating all the list items

Comment: Did you get any warning messages with the error? It could be because of the `try` `except` clause.  Btw I think you can also move `commit` to outside the loop. You don't need to commit after every transaction.

Comment: no warning messages, I just tried moving commit outside of loop and it is throwing an error ``` ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)```

Comment: I just dont understand why this "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)" error pops up again n again. is something wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you post your `User` model class? I suspect the error lies there. And add `print(i)` in the loop to see exactly what you are putting into the `User`.

Comment: here is my user class
```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    listOfItems = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    query = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    current_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.listOfItems}','{self.query}', '{self.current_date}')"
```

Comment: Thanks, can you also share the entire stack trace. That will help pin point where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code has an issue. for i in items means the value at that index, not the index itself. So the first iteration will return 'abc' and so on.

```
  for i in items:
      user = User(listOfItems=items[i], query=query)
      db.session.add(user)
      db.session.commit()
```

Assuming that you want to have the values of the list and insert them, change the line to

```
      user = User(listOfItems=i, query=query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some problems:

- you do not need the `if request.method == 'POST'` statement, you've already declared method in the `route` decorator.
- `for i in items` returns each element from `items`, the `i` variable is not an index; so, `user = User(listOfItems=items[i], query=query)` is incorrect.

I'm not sure these will solve your problem or not; but if not, please show the output of `items` and `output`.